# Two containers that have the same volume (let say 500 liter) but are different in shape

Tags: fluid-dynamics, speed, flow, volume

I remember from school, one time a teacher explain us the following:
two containers of the same volume, but one is thin and tall, and the second is short and wide.
then if we fill them with water from the same input, the container that is thin and tall will get filled faster.
he gave us some mathematical proofs on it, but it was 30 years ago.
does anyone knows if this is true and how can be proved?

Comment: You're probably not accurately remembering what he said because the result that you stated is incorrect.

Comment: You might be talking about the change in height of the water? The thin and tall will obviously have more change in height.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true. Imagine each container displaces one liter and that we are feeding these containers with a constant-speed pump running at one liter per minute. It will then take one minute to fill either of those two containers; their shape has nothing to do with it.